# How to prevent vertically growing field overlapping other objects?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I use `Can Grow` on a field.

A picture of the problem :

[image]

When the text field `names` expands, all other text field should expands too and all line objects should adjust accordingly.

Comment: Separate section for row contain can grow objects

Comment: I use (can grow)  in all text objects for report

Comment: Create a new section below and add the can grow text object in that a section it will eliminate the overlapping

Comment: thanks  Mahendra , who to this please step by step ?

Comment: @Sraj Do you still need help on this?

Comment: thanks @dd4711 , Yes, I still need a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each "row" of your form in different sections. When a field grows vertically your section expands and all following sections will adjust.

I assume you print in the `Detail` section. For your example:

[image: example]

If `{yourtable.names}` vertically expands the whole section `Details b` will move down.

Make sure to draw your vertical lines into the following section or to check `Extend to Bottom of Section when Printing` in the Line Format Editor - or else 
your line will be too short if a text field inside a section expands.

Comment: @SrajMuneer Thank you! Vote it up if you like.